# Unit testing file download for NestJS using Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I want to know how can I test the file downloaded is the file I want from just backend. Most tutorials/instructions I saw is test from frontend side. I want to know is it possible to test just the backend API using Jest? Thanks in advance!

This is the code for controller:

```
@Post('downloadDB')
async downloadDB(@Res() res: Response) {
    return this.configPageService.downloadDB(res);
}
```

This is the code for service:

```
async downloadDB(res: Response) {
    try {
        const admzip = require('adm-zip')
        var configService = new ConfigService();
        var dbPath = configService.dbSource;
        var zip = new admzip();
        var outputFilePath = Date.now() + "_lbkpngr.zip";
        zip.addLocalFile(dbPath);
        fs.writeFileSync(outputFilePath, zip.toBuffer());
        res.download(outputFilePath, (err) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            fs.unlink(outputFilePath, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        res.status(500).end();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use mock-fs? (Which is not really a unit testing but more kind of integration tests)

Comment: @RazLuvaton Any sample code to shed some light on my issue?